# Unable to convert string to Timestamp

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to convert a sample 12 hour date with AM/PM into a timestamp, however, Snowflake is throwing an error that it's not parsable:

`SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('7/16/2021 4:52:25 AM', 'MM/dd/yyyy HH12:mm:ss AM')`

The error message returned:

> Can't parse '7/16/2021 4:52:25 AM' as timestamp with format 'MM/dd/yyyy HH12:mm:ss AM'

I've tried the hours as both `HH` and `HH12` to no avail.

Comment: Try this select to_timestamp('7/16/2021 4:52:25', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh12:mi:ss');

Comment: You're using **mm** for minutes when it should be **mi**. Change that and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to extract only the time part you can use the below statement:

`SELECT TO_TIME(TO_TIMESTAMP('7/16/2021 4:52:25 AM', 'MM/dd/yyyy HH12:mi:ss AM'))`

If you want to convert it to a timestamp format, you can use the below statement:

`SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('7/16/2021 4:52:25 AM', 'MM/dd/yyyy HH12:mi:ss AM')`

PFB the documentation links for date extract:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/date_part.html

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/date_trunc.html